# How to associate a custom URI scheme (e.g., sms:) with Microsoft Phone Link app on Windows

Tags: windows, sms, uri

I am attempting to create a custom URI scheme in Windows that allows me to click on sms: links in my web browser (Chrome) and have those links open the Microsoft Phone Link app to send an SMS message.

I've created a new registry key at HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sms and associated it with the PhoneExperienceHost.exe executable located at "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.YourPhone_1.23052.122.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\PhoneExperienceHost.exe" "%1". However, when I click on sms: links in my browser, Windows does not associate the link with the Phone Link app. Instead, it only offers me the options to open the link with Chrome or Edge. I feel like this isn't where I would encounter an error with trying to use this uri schema if it wasn't possible, that should happen after I select the app and it should tell me its not compatible (I just need to see this for myself).

I realize that the phone link app has no documentation surround this uri schema and it may not be possible but to be fair there is very little documentation on phone link to begin with. I was successfully able to do this with tel links to enable click to call functionality, now I just want to do the texting part.

Please note I am using Windows 11.